# How to split image into square parts? (formula)

Tags: math

I know image size and needed count of parts.
For example, image: 9000x6000 (px), needed count of parts: 1000. What will be the formula for getting a square size?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also is this homework?  If so please make sure this question does not violate the [Honor Code](https://www.chegg.com/honorcode) of the academic establishment issuing the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let dimensions are `Width`, `Height`, needed count is `n` and unknown size is `x`

Every row of grid contains

```
nr =  Floor(Width / x)   // rounding down
```

Every column contains

```
nc = Floor(Height / x)
```

Write inequality

```
n <= nc * nr
n <=  Floor(Width / x) * Floor(Height / x)
```

and solve it (find maximal possible x value) for unknown `x`

Use initial approximation

```
x0 = Ceil(Sqrt(Width * Height / n))  //rounding up
```

and decrement `x` value until inequality becomes true

Comment: Thanks, it's pretty close to solution. But what if I need "n = nc * nr". Strictly 1000 parts and image size something like 9921x6945. Image can be cropped, if needed (I will just add some x/y offset later).

Comment: Described approach is suitable for placement at least n squares onto big rectangle (for examples, photos on the wall), leaving empty places at the last row. If you need to get exactly n (1000), you should factorize n onto 2 divisors with ratio close to Width/Height. It is not always possible (for example, we can represent n=1000 as 25x40, but n= 961 has the only factorization 31x31, n=1006 has the only factorization 2*503 ). So we need to define appropriate strategy for such cases.